# Why can't i fill this class's function pointer with this other class's function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, function-pointers

Now how about a class's function pointer to another class's function? That's my question

Example:

```
class Apple
{
   int(Apple::*pActionFunc)(void);
};

class Tree
{
   Apple* tempy;

   void Init( void );

   int I_Work( void );
};

void Tree::Init( void )
{
  tempy = new Apple( );
  tempy->pActionFunc = &Tree::I_Work;
}

int Tree::I_Work( void )
{
   "Do Things"
}
```

That will not work. Why is that?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx This is a very good read about method pointers. Enjoy and hope it helps

Comment: Why do you use function pointers when you could use functors or interfaces??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work, because like all variables function pointers also have an type and you can only use an pointer to same type to store address of an variable type.

```
int(Apple::*pActionFunc)(void);
```

Tells the compiler that `pActionFunc` is a pointer to an member function of `Apple` class which takes `void` as an parameter and returns an `int`.

```
tempy->pActionFunc = &Tree::I_Work;
```

Tries to store the address of an function `I_Work()` which is member of `Tree` class an which takes `void` as input parameter and returns an `int`.

If you notice they are members functions of different classes and hence the error.

Comment: anyway I can make this work? all i need is the first classto be able to hold a function pointer which connects to functions in the second class

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(int);
void (*pfunc)(double);
pfunc = foo;           // This is an error
```

Why is that an error?  Because pfunc takes a different parameter than foo.  That's sort of the same thing that's going on here.  It may appear that `Tree::I_Work` is a function that takes no parameters and returns an int, and so it should be compatible with a function from Apple that takes no parameters and returns an int.  But that's not the case.  You can't call I_Work like this:

```
x = I_Work();
```

Can you?  No.  You need a Tree object.

```
a_tree.I_Work();
```

This should clue you in that member functions are fundamentally different than free functions.  Member functions have a hidden parameter.  Actually, it's not really hidden at all, it's just in a different location.  It's to the left of the function name instead of in the parentheses.

So, to sum up, you can't assign one class' member function pointer to another class' member function, because they don't take the same arguments, even though they appear to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Als said, you cannot assign the following:

```
tempy->pActionFunc = &Tree::I_Work;
```

As `I_Work` has an implicit `this` pointer as an argument, and therefore the argument lists are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Every member function has an invisible `this` parameter that is part of the function signature. When you write:

```
int(Apple::*pActionFunc)(void);
```

Internally the compiler treats it as:

```
int(*pActionFunc)(Apple* this);
```

The function that you're trying to insert into the pointer has the following signature equivalent:

```
int I_Work(Tree* this);
```

The signatures don't match.